# Using boolean result, add to enum to pass as argument?

Tags: c#, enums

I am trying to build up a set of enum selections to pass to an argument to another method. Let's assume you have the enum **Foo**, as specified below:

```
public enum Foo
{
   x,
   y,
   z
}
```

Now, I am going to loop through some checkbox selections, each that specifies whether X, Y, or Z is selected.

```
bool allowX = chkBxAllowX.Checked;
bool allowY = chkBxAllowY.Checked;
bool allowZ = allowZ.Checked;
```

Following, I have to build up the selections to pass as the **Foo** enum type. I know I can specify multiple enum values by using the **"|"** character, but how to do this based on other values (namely, the above Boolean values?). So if allowX, add Foo.x, if allowY, specify Add Foo.y. If allowX and allowY, Foo.x and Foo.y.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you need a default value in your enum (and mark it with the `FlagsAttribute`):

```
[Flags]
public enum Foo
{
  NoSelection = 0,
  X = 1, 
  Y = 2
  Z = 4
}
```

Once that's done, you can use the `|=` assignment to add the flags based on checkbox status. e.g.

```
Foo foo = Foo.NoSelection;

if (allowX) foo |= Foo.X;
if (allowY) foo |= Foo.Y;
if (allowZ) foo |= Foo.Z;
```

Then, if you want to verify:

```
bool allowX = true;
bool allowY = false;
bool allowZ = true;

Foo foo = Foo.NoSelection;

if (allowX) foo |= Foo.X;
if (allowY) foo |= Foo.Y;
if (allowZ) foo |= Foo.Z;

Console.WriteLine("allowX = {0}", ((foo & Foo.X) == Foo.X) ? "true" : "false");
Console.WriteLine("allowY = {0}", ((foo & Foo.Y) == Foo.Y) ? "true" : "false");
Console.WriteLine("allowZ = {0}", ((foo & Foo.Z) == Foo.Z) ? "true" : "false");
```

Comment: You still need to define your values as powers of 2 if you want to be able to combine them. As it is now, Z == X & Y

Comment: @MattBurland: Indeed. Was typing too quick. Fixed & added example. thanks for the feedback.

Comment: you can bitshift them, which is nice:
X = 2<<0, Y = 2<<1, Z = 2<<2 and so on

Answer (score 0):

> I know I can specify multiple enum values by using the "|" character

That would be the bitwise OR operator and no, you can't, not with your current enum anyway.  Since you did not assign values explicitly the compiler will assign sequential values fort you.

To use an enum as a bitfield each value must represent a specific set of binary positions (bits), i.e., powers of 2. So...

```
[Flags]  
public enum Foo
{
   None = 0,
   X    = 0x01,
   Y    = 0x02,
   Z    = 0x04
}

// ...
Foo f = Foo.None;
if (chkBxAllowX.Checked)
    f |= Foo.X;
if (chkBxAllowY.Checked)
    f |= Foo.Y;
if (chkBxAllowZ.Checked)
    f |= Foo.Z;  

SomeMethod(f);
```

You can later check your permissions with:

```
void SomeMethod(Foo f)
{
    if (f.HasFlag(Foo.X))
    // or...
    if ((f & Foo.X) == Foo.X)
}
```

Comment: You should also use the `Flags` attribute.

Comment: @MattBurland: `[Flags]` is only for pretty printing, but sure, why not.

Comment: @EdS. It is more than purely cosmetic. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163568.aspx#S7): *"It is interesting to note that when Flags is specified, Parse and Format methods feature advanced capabilities."* Also, other classes may look up the `FlagsAttribute` to do additional logic for handling the enum type.

Comment: @SiLo: `Format` would be exactly what I was referring to, but I didn't know about additional parsing capability.  Thanks.

Comment: @EdS. Either way, it's a good habit to mark enums meant to be used as flags with `Flags` to make your intent clear to anybody else looking at your code.